# ListView item background changes depending on scroll position

Tags: android, listview, background-color, baseadapter

I'm running into a very strange ListView behaviour. I have a simple chat application which uses a ListView and a custom implementation of BaseAdapter to show messages.

The idea I had was to shade messages from the "local" user grey and have messages from the "remote" user white, to help the user distinguish between the two.
The two screenshots below show what's happening. The second is the exact same activity, xml etc etc, simply scrolled down a bit.

Scrolled up:

[image: scrolled up image]

Scrolled down:

[image: scrolled down image]

Look at the message sent by "Me" @ 23:05. When at the top it has no contrast to its neighbours, but when it is scrolled to the bottom, the difference is clear to see.
This occurs on a nexus 4 and 7 on 4.2.2, and a GS3 running 4.1.2.

Here is the XML for one of the ListView items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_view_conversation_message_list_item_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/activity_view_conversation_message_list_item_user_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/default_user_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_view_conversation_message_list_item_heading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/activity_view_conversation_message_list_item_user_image"
        android:text="Martyn"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_view_conversation_message_list_item_contents"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/activity_view_conversation_message_list_item_heading"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/activity_view_conversation_message_list_item_ack"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/activity_view_conversation_message_list_item_user_image"
        android:text="Hello this is some text"
        android:textColor="#333333"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_view_conversation_message_list_item_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:text="12:08"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/activity_view_conversation_message_list_item_ack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/activity_view_conversation_message_list_item_time"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/activity_view_conversation_message_list_item_time"
        android:src="@drawable/red_dot_8dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is where I set the colour of the RelativeLayout:

```
if(localUserId.equals(remoteUserId)){
    itemLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F9F9F9"));
}
```

That code runs inside the getView() method of my Adapter.

I've Googled this a fair bit and turned up nothing, there are a lot of SO questions regarding the android:cacheColorHint issue but I don't think that is what is going on here.

Has anyone run into this before? I'm stumped!

EDIT: Here's the baseadapter code:

```
public class MessageListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Message> messageList;
    Context context;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param newConversationsList  An ArrayList of Conversation objects that this adapter will use
     * @param newContext            The context of the activity that instantiated this adapter
     */
    MessageListAdapter(ArrayList<Message> newMessageList, Context newContext){
        messageList = newMessageList;
        //reload();
        context = newContext;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return messageList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return messageList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a message to the chat list
     * @param message       A Message object containing all the message's information
     */
    public void add(Message message){
        //nMessagesToShow++;        //A new message has been added, so increase the number to show by one
        Log.d(TAG, "COUNT: "+getCount());
        //refresh();
    }

    public void refresh(){
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if(view!=null){
            //return view;
        }

        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //Get the Message object from the list
        Message message = messageList.get(position);

        //Get the data from the message
        String senderId = message.getFromUser();
        int messageType = message.getType();

        String senderFirstName;

        ImageView userImage, messageImage;
        TextView messageHeading, messageBody;

        switch(messageType){
        case Message.MESSAGE_TYPE_TEXT:             //Standard text message
            //The layout we inflate for this list item will vary depending on whether this message has the same sender as the previous
            if(position>0 && senderId.equals(messageList.get(position-1).getFromUser())){       //True if this is not the first message AND the sender id matches that of the previous message              
                view = vi.inflate(R.layout.activity_view_conversation_message_list_item_alternate, null);       //Inflate an alternate version of the list item which has no heading or user image
            }
            else{       //This is the first message OR the sender id is different to the previous               
                view = vi.inflate(R.layout.activity_view_conversation_message_list_item, null);                 //Inflate the standard version of the layout

                userImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.activity_view_conversation_message_list_item_user_image);
                messageHeading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.activity_view_conversation_message_list_item_heading);

                //Use the sender's ID to get the sender's image and first name
                Contact contact = database.getContact(senderId);
                if(senderId.equals(localUserId)){       //True if the local user sent this message
                    senderFirstName = "Me";
                }
                else{
                    senderFirstName = contact.getFirstName();
                }
                userImage.setImageBitmap(contact.getImageBitmap(100, 100, 6));
                messageHeading.setText(senderFirstName);
            }

            messageBody = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.activity_view_conversation_message_list_item_contents);
            messageBody.setText(message.getContents(null));

            break;              
        case Message.MESSAGE_TYPE_IMAGE:            //Image message
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.activity_view_conversation_message_list_item_image, null);       //Inflate a list item template for displaying an image
            userImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.activity_view_conversation_message_list_item_user_image);

            //Sender's first name
            messageHeading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.activity_view_conversation_message_list_item_heading);
            Contact contact = database.getContact(senderId);
            if(senderId.equals(localUserId)){       //True if the local user sent this message
                senderFirstName = "Me";
            }
            else{
                senderFirstName = contact.getFirstName();
            }
            messageHeading.setText(senderFirstName);
            messageImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.activity_view_conversation_message_list_item_image);
            String imageResourceId = null;
            //The message is a JSON object containing several fields, one of which is the file name which we will use to get the image
            try {
                JSONObject messageJSON = new JSONObject(message.getContents(null));
                String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/epicChat/resources/"+messageJSON.getString("fileName");
                int imageWidth = messageJSON.getInt("width");       //We want the dimensions in order to calculate the aspect ratio of the image
                int imageHeight = messageJSON.getInt("height");
                if(messageJSON.has("resourceId")){
                    imageResourceId = messageJSON.getString("resourceId");  //This is used when opening the image gallery
                }
                int displayWidth = 300;
                int displayHeight = (int) ((float) imageHeight / (float) imageWidth * (float) displayWidth);
                String imagePathFull = imagePath+displayWidth+displayHeight;            //For the caching
                Bitmap originalImage = null;
                //Check the bitmap cache exists. If not, reinstantiate it
                if(MainActivity.bitmapCache==null){                 //Cache is null
                    MainActivity.loadBitmapCache();
                }
                else{                                               //Cache is not null, so check it to see if this image is in it
                    originalImage = MainActivity.bitmapCache.get(imagePathFull);
                }
                if(originalImage==null){        //True if the bitmap was not in the cache. So we must load from disk instead
                    new Utils.LoadBitmapAsync(imagePath, messageImage, displayWidth, displayHeight, MainActivity.bitmapCache).execute();
                    messageImage.getLayoutParams().height = displayHeight;
                }
                else{
                    messageImage.setImageBitmap(originalImage);
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error reading image JSON: "+e.toString());
            }
            if(imageResourceId!=null){      //Only attach the listener if we got a valid resource ID
                final String recourceIdFinal = imageResourceId;
                final String conversationIdFinal =  message.getUserList();
                messageImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent showConversationImageGalleryIntent = new Intent(context, ViewConversationImageGalleryActivity.class);
                        showConversationImageGalleryIntent.putExtra("conversationId", conversationIdFinal);
                        showConversationImageGalleryIntent.putExtra("resourceId", recourceIdFinal);
                        startActivityForResult(showConversationImageGalleryIntent, ACTION_SHOW_CONVERSATION_IMAGE_GALLERY);
                    }
                });
            }
            userImage.setImageBitmap(contact.getImageBitmap(100, 100, 6));
            break;
        case Message.MESSAGE_TYPE_INVALID:
        default:
            break;
        }

        //Some layout items are present in all layouts. Typically these are the status indicator and the message time
        RelativeLayout itemLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.activity_view_conversation_message_list_item_wrapper);
        //If the message is from the local user, give it a subtle grey background
        if(localUserId.equals(message.getFromUser())){
            itemLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E9E9E9"));
        }
        else{
            itemLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        }
        TextView messageTimeText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.activity_view_conversation_message_list_item_time);
        messageTimeText.setText(message.getFormattedTime());

        ImageView messageStatusImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.activity_view_conversation_message_list_item_ack);
        //Set the status image according to the status of the message
        switch(message.getStatus()){
        case Message.MESSAGE_STATUS_PENDING:        //Pending messages should have a red dot
            messageStatusImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_dot_8dp);
            messageStatusImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case Message.MESSAGE_STATUS_ACK_SERVER:     //Messages that reached the server should have an orange dot
            messageStatusImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange_dot_8dp);
            messageStatusImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case Message.MESSAGE_STATUS_ACK_RECIPIENT:  //Messages that reached the recipient should have an green dot
            messageStatusImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_dot_8dp);
            messageStatusImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case Message.MESSAGE_STATUS_NOT_SET:        //Not set typically means the message came from another user, in which case the status image should be hidden
        default:                                    //Also default here
            messageStatusImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;
        }           
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post the code for your implementation of BaseAdapter

Comment: Added the code for the adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's no else statement matching your if, this is probably due to view recycling. When an item from a ListView scrolls off the screen, the operating system removes it and hands it back to the adapter in the same state it was removed. This means you need to set the background color when it's not the local user's message as well.

Comment: That solved it, however it seems I'm not understanding view recycling properly. The problem I show in the two screenshots happens even when the view in question does not go off the screen, so it shouldn't be recycled should it? I can see it changing colour as I drag it down, and it stays in the visible area the whole time. It just seems a very weird side-effect of recycling to me.

Comment: First thing is the way you have implemented your getView method will making your app very slow because you are calling findViewById every time. You should not do this. whenever you scroll a list internally it call onDraw method which redraw your list. so if you don't put else condition background of that row will be grey.

Comment: I have been reading up on getView and it does seem like I should use the item id method to allow me to recycle the views. But none of the answers here really explain why the background colour of the list item gradually changes from white to grey. I could understand if it was suddenly changing, but this is a smooth change, from FFFFFF to DDDDDD, where the item is FFFFFF if it is at the top of the container, but as I pull it down, it slowly changes to DDDDDD. Something else must be going on here, as the colour is being interpolated depending on how far down the page the item is. I'm just curious

Comment: This could just be an optical illusion due to the fact that the Holo theme uses subtle gradients by default. Try setting the window background to a solid color and check if the problem persists. https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable/background_holo_light.xml

Comment: This was such a help!!! I had a background converter that did have an if but the else was returning null instead of transparent. Every other method wouldn't work. Thanks a ton!